# Convert to localtime in the past sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone

I am storing timestamps in database as expressed in UTC, e.g. '2015-03-27 08:32:46.024 +00:00'

And I am using the current servers timezone to convert the timestamps to local time.

```
select 
    SWITCHOFFSET (CAST(CAST('2015-03-27 08:32:00.000 +00:00' AS datetime2(3)) as DateTimeOffset(3)), DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ()) )
```

This works fine as long as I look to wintertime timestamps in wintertime.

For last Fridays time wintertime timestamp get expressed in summer time: '2015-03-27 10:32:00.000 +02:00'.

I would like to see 2015-03-27 09:32:00.000 +01:00.

Anyone that has a solution without storing winter- and summertime in the database?

Comment: winter time... i think you're referring to daylight saving savings right?

Comment: I would guess you'd have to use "AdjustForDST" flag since not every coutry/territory uses Daylight Savings.

Comment: @samyi Correct it is about daylight saving, where can I find this AdjustForDST flag ?

Comment: I think he means you'd have to create one in your table.

Comment: This is usually best done in application code rather than the database, unless you have a very specific reason why it needs to be done at the db level.

Comment: @samyi - Not only that, but those countries that *do* use DST use it in all sorts of different ways.  The transition dates and times vary wildly.  You can't rely on a simple flag.

Comment: You could use SQL CLR to access the .NET TimeZoneInfo data.

Comment: Thanks all, I want to see the time in local CET only, maybe I should just create a simple management table with year, begin- and end summer time.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the question's comments, this is usually best done in application code, rather than in the database.  However, there are some scenarios where having it in the database can be quite useful, or necessary.  For example, you may need to *group by* a date in a specific time zone, or you may need to convert many items in bulk, or generate data for a reporting system.

For these, you can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.

Follow the installation instructions, then you can do this:

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal('2015-03-27 08:32:46.024', 'Europe/Paris')
```

I am guessing at your time zone.  You can choose any [from the list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).